# missing format error

Tags: debugging

Hi Guys I am having a missing format: 1. alert on my web most of the time is when loging out of my web on when I access the front page, this is the log message

filter
Date    Saturday, August 1, 2015 - 11:16

User    raydelhgm

Location    http://localhost/gameswapuk/

Message Missing text format: 1.

Severity    alert

Hostname    127.0.0.1

how could i fix it, thanks

Comment: a little googling reveals: https://www.drupal.org/node/1393076#comment-5426388